# Reducing the complexity of getting unique values from dict in Python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, time-complexity

I am fairly new to Python (and writing good and efficient algorithms) and am not too familiar with the different data structures that can be used to iterate over large amounts of data efficiently. I need to find the unique set of values from a nested dict, and have written the following code:

```
data = {'c14da622-7fb8-4da3-a2fb-d8c632957fbe': {'25': {'label': 'no plane'}, '50': {'label': 'no plane'}, '125': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '175': {'label': 'plane'}, '200': {'label': 'plane'}, '275': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '325': {'label': 'plane'}, '350': {'label': 'plane'}, '375': {'label': 'plane'}, '400': {'label': 'plane'}, '425': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '475': {'label': 'plane'}, '500': {'label': 'plane'}, '525': {'label': 'plane'}, '550': {'label': 'plane'}, '575': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '625': {'label': 'plane'}, '650': {'label': 'plane'}, '875': {'label': 'plane'}, '900': {'label': 'plane'}, '925': {'label': 'plane'}, '950': {'label': 'plane'}, '975': {'label': 'plane'}, '1000': {'label': 'plane'}, '1025': {'label': 'plane'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane'}, '1075': {'label': 'plane'}, '1100': {'label': 'plane'}, '1125': {'label': 'plane'}, '1150': {'label': 'plane'}, '1175': {'label': 'plane'}}, '60cb59c7-6b0a-4225-b00f-2d888a9d5250': {'30': {'label': 'no plane'}, '60': {'label': 'no plane'}, '90': {'label': 'no plane'}, '120': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '180': {'label': 'plane'}, '210': {'label': 'plane'}, '240': {'label': 'plane'}, '270': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '330': {'label': 'plane'}, '360': {'label': 'plane'}, '390': {'label': 'plane'}, '420': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '480': {'label': 'plane'}, '510': {'label': 'plane'}, '570': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '660': {'label': 'plane'}, '690': {'label': 'plane'}, '720': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '750': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '780': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '810': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '840': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '870': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '900': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '930': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '960': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '990': {'label': 'no plane'}, '1020': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1080': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1110': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1140': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1170': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1200': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1230': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1260': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1290': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1320': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1350': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1380': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1410': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1560': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1590': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1620': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1650': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1680': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1710': {'label': 'plane crash'}}}

def parse_label_categories(data):
    tuples = list(data.values())
    unique_labels = []
    for labels in tuples:
        labels_dump = list(labels.values())
        for dump in labels_dump:
            label = list(dump.values())
            new = label.pop()
            unique_labels.append(new)
    return list(set(unique_labels))

parse_label_categories(data)
```

Which returns the three unique values:

```
['plane crash', 'plane', 'no plane']
```

I have a nested for loop and overall my code is pretty atrocious, but I have been hard pressed to find a more elegant and efficient solution to this problem in Python.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: If you don't convert your `.values` to list, you will reduce space complexity - converting creates new object. You can also operate on set `unique_labels`, rather than a list - right now the list contains every label in the loop, not unique labels.

Comment: Another issue - yo don't have to pop, you know how much items the "labels_dump" has - exactly one, labelled "label". | Two for loops are okay. With fixes I mentioned, you can even convert it to a one-liner set comprehension: `unique_labels = {labelled["label"] for subdict in data.values() for labelled in subdict.values()}` (or to keep your names from the loops: `unique_labels = {labels_dump["label"] for labels in data.values() for labels_dump in labels.values()}` - but I think my names are more logical :P )

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions :-) I'm fiddling with the re-write. I like the one-liner set comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro-tip: [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) will format data into a readable format, even if that JSON has already been parsed into a python list/dict.

```
data = {'c14da622-7fb8-4da3-a2fb-d8c632957fbe': {'25': {'label': 'no plane'}, '50': {'label': 'no plane'}, '125': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '175': {'label': 'plane'}, '200': {'label': 'plane'}, '275': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '325': {'label': 'plane'}, '350': {'label': 'plane'}, '375': {'label': 'plane'}, '400': {'label': 'plane'}, '425': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '475': {'label': 'plane'}, '500': {'label': 'plane'}, '525': {'label': 'plane'}, '550': {'label': 'plane'}, '575': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '625': {'label': 'plane'}, '650': {'label': 'plane'}, '875': {'label': 'plane'}, '900': {'label': 'plane'}, '925': {'label': 'plane'}, '950': {'label': 'plane'}, '975': {'label': 'plane'}, '1000': {'label': 'plane'}, '1025': {'label': 'plane'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane'}, '1075': {'label': 'plane'}, '1100': {'label': 'plane'}, '1125': {'label': 'plane'}, '1150': {'label': 'plane'}, '1175': {'label': 'plane'}}, '60cb59c7-6b0a-4225-b00f-2d888a9d5250': {'30': {'label': 'no plane'}, '60': {'label': 'no plane'}, '90': {'label': 'no plane'}, '120': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '180': {'label': 'plane'}, '210': {'label': 'plane'}, '240': {'label': 'plane'}, '270': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '330': {'label': 'plane'}, '360': {'label': 'plane'}, '390': {'label': 'plane'}, '420': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '480': {'label': 'plane'}, '510': {'label': 'plane'}, '570': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '660': {'label': 'plane'}, '690': {'label': 'plane'}, '720': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '750': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '780': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '810': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '840': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '870': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '900': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '930': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '960': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '990': {'label': 'no plane'}, '1020': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1080': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1110': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1140': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1170': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1200': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1230': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1260': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1290': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1320': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1350': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1380': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1410': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1560': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1590': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1620': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1650': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1680': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1710': {'label': 'plane crash'}}}

def parse_label_categories(data):
    seen = set()
    for some_lable, data_dict in data.items():
        for some_number, outcome in data_dict.items():
            seen.add(outcome['label'])
    return seen

a = parse_label_categories(data)
```

I don't think there is a more efficient approach to this in Python. You might be able to use pandas and possibly push the loops into C, as it expands out the JSON into a dataframe, but I'm not convinced.

---

Since the pandas approach *did* come up, I did the timings:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'c14da622-7fb8-4da3-a2fb-d8c632957fbe': {'25': {'label': 'no plane'}, '50': {'label': 'no plane'}, '125': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '175': {'label': 'plane'}, '200': {'label': 'plane'}, '275': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '325': {'label': 'plane'}, '350': {'label': 'plane'}, '375': {'label': 'plane'}, '400': {'label': 'plane'}, '425': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '475': {'label': 'plane'}, '500': {'label': 'plane'}, '525': {'label': 'plane'}, '550': {'label': 'plane'}, '575': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '625': {'label': 'plane'}, '650': {'label': 'plane'}, '875': {'label': 'plane'}, '900': {'label': 'plane'}, '925': {'label': 'plane'}, '950': {'label': 'plane'}, '975': {'label': 'plane'}, '1000': {'label': 'plane'}, '1025': {'label': 'plane'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane'}, '1075': {'label': 'plane'}, '1100': {'label': 'plane'}, '1125': {'label': 'plane'}, '1150': {'label': 'plane'}, '1175': {'label': 'plane'}}, '60cb59c7-6b0a-4225-b00f-2d888a9d5250': {'30': {'label': 'no plane'}, '60': {'label': 'no plane'}, '90': {'label': 'no plane'}, '120': {'label': 'no plane'}, '150': {'label': 'no plane'}, '180': {'label': 'plane'}, '210': {'label': 'plane'}, '240': {'label': 'plane'}, '270': {'label': 'plane'}, '300': {'label': 'plane'}, '330': {'label': 'plane'}, '360': {'label': 'plane'}, '390': {'label': 'plane'}, '420': {'label': 'plane'}, '450': {'label': 'plane'}, '480': {'label': 'plane'}, '510': {'label': 'plane'}, '570': {'label': 'plane'}, '600': {'label': 'plane'}, '660': {'label': 'plane'}, '690': {'label': 'plane'}, '720': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '750': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '780': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '810': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '840': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '870': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '900': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '930': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '960': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '990': {'label': 'no plane'}, '1020': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1050': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1080': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1110': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1140': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1170': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1200': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1230': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1260': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1290': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1320': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1350': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1380': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1410': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1560': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1590': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1620': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1650': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1680': {'label': 'plane crash'}, '1710': {'label': 'plane crash'}}}

def parse_label_categories(data):
    seen = set()
    for some_lable, data_dict in data.items():
        for some_number, outcome in data_dict.items():
            seen.add(outcome['label'])
    return seen


def pandas_approach(d):
    all_df=None 
    for id, d in data.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
        if all_df is None:
            all_df = df
        else:
            all_df = pd.concat([all_df, df])
```

Which gives:

```
%timeit parse_label_categories(data)
18 µs ± 2.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit pandas_approach(data)
2.7 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I generally don't like using pandas as I have tried using them before, and they always seem to be extremely slow. I hadn't thought of the jsonlist approach, very elegant. And super fast it seems :-) Thanks very much! How did you do the timings if I can ask?

Comment: @ulsha lots of things about the pandas API are unintuitive. It actually _does_ perform much faster on a lot of different tasks but, in this case, it's a lot of extra overhead that you don't need

Comment: @ulsha I use Spyder as my IDE. It comes with IPython and the ["magic"](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) methods it has. `timeit` is also a module, but IPython makes some things much easier

Comment: Nice - I'll check out timeit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could turn this into a dataframe and significantly reduce the amount of looping you need to do. You would still have to loop on the first level and then concatenate the results, but as the rest would make use of vectorization in the background it could be significantly faster:

```
import pandas as pd
all_df=None 
for id, d in data.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
    if all_df is None:
        all_df = df
    else:
        all_df = pd.concat([all_df, df])

print(all_df["label"].unique())
```

Comment: lol, you tested the theory at the end of my answer. Now there's no choice but to time it :)